# Escape a dollar sign in a regex replacement string

Tags: regex, go

I have a function in which I need to replace "byte" with "$ball". This doesn't seem to work correctly.
Here is the program snippet.

```
fun main() {

    str := []byte("$apple in a byte\n")
    strReplace := "$ball"

    re := regexp.MustCompile("byte")

    final := re.ReplaceAll(str, []byte(strReplace))

    ioutil.WriteFile("testfile.txt", final, 0744)
}
```

Expected Output in testfile.txt:
    $apple in a $ball

Actual Output in testfile.txt:
    $apple in a

Any solutions for successfully getting the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `$$` which is exactly what the documentation tells you. You do have to follow the paper trail to get right down to the final word though.

The godoc section for `ReplaceAll` (https://godoc.org/regexp#Regexp.ReplaceAll) tells you:

> $ signs are interpreted as in Expand

So reading the section for `Expand` has the answer right at the end. https://godoc.org/regexp#Regexp.Expand

> To insert a literal $ in the output, use $$ in the template.

Comment: My bad! I was assuming this is an issue with byte type and searching in this docs only.